# JavaScript regex only capturing first match

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

[image]

I need to parse multiple email bodies that look like using google apps script:

```
Name: Bob smith
Email: hellol@aol.com
Phone Number: 4243331212
```

I want to split on the heading at the beginning of each line .I have the following function:

```
function parseBody (i, body) {

   var split = body.split(new RegExp(/(\w*): ([^\t\r\n]*)[\t\r\n]*/)) //removes trailing line feed

 .filter(function (x) { return x })

 .....


 }
```

but the regex is not working, only capturing the first title when I test on http://www.regexpal.com/ . What am I doing wrong?

edit:

[image]

Comment: @Toto,  This is not a duplicate , the first question was about a syntax error. The current question is because the regex is not functioning  as I expected and 
 I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `g` flag to make sure it doesn't stop after the first match.

```
/(\w*):/g
```

[Demo](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=98751)

Then, your whole regex is:

```
/(\w*): ([^\t\r\n]*)[\t\r\n]*/g
```

You might want to change it to `(^[^:]+)` though, so you can have spaces in the first part (like in Phone Number). Also, add a `m` flag to make it multiline:

```
 /(^[^:]+): ([^\t\r\n]*)[\t\r\n]*/mg
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lRxpNT/1)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  that is a step in the right direction, but if you switch to JS (https://regex101.com/r/lRxpNT/1) it gives a full match. I want to either split on the title (the part before the colon) or  somehow end up with the part after the colons on each line in an array. I've added a screenshot above.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use regex? It'd be much easier and faster to split each line on `:` and use the first and second part in the array accordingly.

Comment: There may be some free text in the email bodies besides what I'm showing, but it might be worth a try.